# PS script for adding custom attributes from exchange into an AD object

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am working on a custom script to add some custom attributes from our Exchange online to our local AD.

I have an issue passing the value into AD using the `set-aduser` command:

```bsh
#Set UPN of current user from CSV
$UPN = $User.aduser

#Get user's MSOL object
$User = get-msoluser -UserPrincipalName "$UPN@domain.com"

#Get a list of additional email addresses for the user
$userproxies = $user.ProxyAddresses

#Find same user's local AD Object
$LocalADUser = Get-ADUser -Filter {userPrincipalName -eq $user.UserPrincipalName} -Properties * -server Server

#set custom attributes
$CustomAttr1 = get-mailbox  $upn | Select-Object CustomAttribute1
$CustomAttr2 = get-mailbox  $upn | Select-Object CustomAttribute2
$CustomAttr3 = get-mailbox  $upn | Select-Object CustomAttribute3

#Copies properties from MSOL to Local AD Object (minus the ProxyAddresses)
Set-ADUser -server Server -DisplayName $User.DisplayName -Identity $LocalADUser.SamAccountName -Office $User.Office -Company $User.CompanyName -Department $User.Department -Title $User.title -MobilePhone $User.Mobile -OfficePhone $User.TelephoneNumber 

#For each ProxyAddress in the users MSOL Object
foreach ($Proxy in $UserProxies)
{
    #Add the ProxyAddress to the users Local AD Object
    set-ADUser -server Server -Identity $LocalADUser.SamAccountName -Add @{Proxyaddresses=$Proxy}
}

Set-ADUser -server Server -Identity $LocalADUser.SamAccountName -add @{CustomAttribute1=$CustomAttr1}
Set-ADUser -server Server -Identity $LocalADUser.SamAccountName -add @{CustomAttribute2=$CustomAttr2}
Set-ADUser -server Server -Identity $LocalADUser.SamAccountName -add @{CustomAttribute3=$CustomAttr3}
```

I am failing with the last 3 lines. (`-add @(CustomAttribute1=$CustomAttr1`} etc.)

I get the following error

> Set-ADUser : Invalid type 'System.Management.Automation.PSObject'.
>       Parameter name: CustomAttribute1
>       At C:\Users\user\Documents\AD Azure Sync.ps1:51 char:13
>       +             Set-ADUser -server Server -Identity $LocalADUser.SamA ...
>       +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Username:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
>         ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser

Any suggestions on how to resolve, or even improve this?

I would like to convert the custom attribute section into an array and pass it in in a for-each loop, if possible.